# French film from 80-90s about military burning a town to cover up a poison spillage

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for a French film. The film is set in late 70s or 80s. The film starts with a traffic accident involving a military vehicle transporting chemical weapons, toxins.

The plot involved accidental military chemicals, poison spillage (almost certainly agent orange). Military was forced to cover up the accident via burning down small town. There are quite memorable shots of military in protective suits systematically burning down small town. The plot obviously involved  investigation by skeptical journalists and uncovering military's involvement and cover up.

Uncovering the military's involvement includes tense conversations between investigative journalists and military/scientific informer, with the latter revealing classified military programmes involving almost certainly Agent Orange. I am sure of the fact that the Vietnam War and Agent Orange were mentioned. This scene reminds me of Jacob's ladder (1990) that involved similar revelatory scene also using ex military informant.

Comment: Hi. Do you remember what time period the *plot* took place in? Was it during a war? And do you remember any actors or specific characters?

Comment: @user41430 You seem to be the same user as the asker. Please consider merging your two user accounts by following the procedure described [here](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). This will enable you to take full control of your question, including being able to comment, edit, or accept any possible answers.

Comment: Sounds like Zone rouge (1986)

Comment: @user41430 If you know what movie this is please add and answer, do not edit the original post.

Comment: @pori Add it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks to @pori we know the film's title. It is Zone rouge (1986).

Comment: Refer [here](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to know how to merge two accounts. As currently you can't even accept the answer from pori if he provided it.

Comment: @pori It's even confirm now, so better to be added as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

[Zone rouge (1986)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101019/)

From: [allmovie](http://www.allmovie.com/movie/zone-rouge-v121218)

> Claire Rousset (Sabine Azema) heads to a small town to come to the aid of her ailing ex-husband, who has been poisoned by the town's drinking water. As Claire arrives, she sees a band of arsonists burn the city down, lock, stock, and water barrel. The iron-clad official statement is that the incinerated town had an unfortunate gas explosion. This blatant lie propels Claire to find out who torched the town, and why no one in government is listening to her. Meanwhile, Jeff Montellier (Richard Anconina), an employee of a company that transports lethal chemicals, finds out that a dangerous accident in the destroyed town poisoned its water supply. Eventually, Jeff and Claire cross paths in their investigations and discover that they are up against some very powerful enemies.